# An inductive proof associated with binary representation of natural numbers

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, induction

Proposition: Every natural number $n$ can be written, in a unique way,
as a sum of powers of $2$ with nonnegative and pairwise distinct integer exponents.
Answer:
**Base Case**: For $n=1$, $n=2^0$ and thus, the given proposition holds for $1$. Suppose $1=2^x$$(x \in \mathbb N_0)$ where $x \neq 0$. If so,then $x>0$ as it must be non-negative.Thus,$1=2(2^{x-1})$.As $2^{x-1} \geq 1 \Rightarrow 2(2^{x-1})\geq 2>1$ which gives absurd results. We can imitate the same argument for $2$. Now,if $3=2^0+2^1$ can be written in two different ways,subtracting one will give two different ways for $2$ too.($3$ must have $1$ as the term because it is odd).

**Induction Hypothesis** : Suppose the proposition is true for $n=1,2,.....,k$ where $k>2$.
Now,the situation breaks into two cases.
**Case 1**: $k$ is odd
If so then $k+1 > 1$ and $k+1$ must be even. If we take $1 \leq s=\frac{k+1}{2} \leq k-1<k$ and hence, we can write $s$ as:
$$s=2^{a_1}+2^{a_2}+......+2^{a_h}$$ and by multiplying $2$ to both sides,we get,
$$2s=k+1=2^{a_1+1}+2^{a_2+1}+.....+2^{a_h+1}$$ and since, the integral powers were pairwise distinct initially, they will be that, after an increment of $1$. Now,we need to prove the uniqueness of such representation.We can just reverse the argument we put above. Suppose there are two such representations for $k+1$. Each term in there must have a power greater than $0$ since $k+1$ is even.Divide both sides by two to get to get a new number that is less than $k$. This number,due to two different binary representations of $k+1$ will have two different binary representations for itself.But,the induction hypothesis does not approve this. Thus, we can conclude that the given proposition is true for $k+1$.
**Case 2**:$k$ is even
Just take $1<s=\frac{k}{2} <k$ and apply inductive hypothesis as:
$$s= 2^{a_1}+2^{a_2}+......+2^{a_h}$$Just multiply $2$ to both sides and add one so as to get the representation for $k+1$.The term $2^0$ or $1$ can not be in the representation of $2s$ as it is even and thus,adding a one really does lead to the creation of the requisite binary representation of $k+1$. The uniqueness can be verified as in the previous case. The only thing different here is that we have to subtract $1$ from $k+1$ for different representations of $k+1$.
Please let me know if there are any glitches in there.

Comment: Your base case you proved existence but not uniqueness, IE you need to show there is no other way of writing $1$ in binary.  You also need to include 2 and 3 in your base case if you are going to start your inductive hypothesis at $k>2$

Comment: Thank you @Alan. I have tried to add what you asked for. Please let me know if the proof is complete.